# Change a column participating in a view or rule

Tags: postgresql, postgis, alter-table, alter-column

I am using a tool called giswater to model our water sewer and storm networks. The tools builds a database from a few simple inputs in a gui one of which is the SRID. the geometry columns are all xy and I want to make them all ZM aware. When I run the alter table command to update the geometry I get an error "Cannot alter column participating in a view or rule"
Anyway to force this change and ignore the error? I tried changing the view to not reference the column and I tried adding a new geometry column to switch the view to temporarily while I make the change. Apparently I cannot drop a column in a view or change it to another column. I also tried writing the schema to SQL then edited the sql lines for linestring and point to linestringzm and pointzm and using psql to run the file to update the schema; all I get is access denied using "psql -U postgres -d utility -1 -f \i Z:......\xyz_test.sql"
Also tried pg_restore.
Anyway to just force the change using pg_admin4? or other suggestions?

Comment: You can force change by updating directly `pg_attribute`, but I do not recommend it. Why not simply drop view and recreate it using new table structure?

Comment: That was 1 example there are many views not sure how many are referencing "the_geom" arc. arc is all the linestring geometries representing pipes there are several views each one for each type of pipe, several in total. nodes are the same way both will need updating to make a full 3D model. I did find another work around, sort of. I found the sql scripts the gui uses to make the database. I went into the ones that make the tables and changed the geometry columns to zm. How do I directly update pg_attribute and why is that not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the tool you are using but I would suggest checking all the objects (views and rules) referencing your table by using the below command.

SELECT DISTINCT so.name
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'

Then backing up these object and dropping them completely before attempting to alter the table.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly that code should return all the referenced objects, back them up, drop them, update, then restore them?

Comment: No, it will return error, because those tables do not exists in PostgreSQL. Assuming those were pg tables, it would only find objects that are maybe referencing table you want to alter.

Comment: I couldn't get the command to work; with that said I am not sure if it is my ability or the command itself. There has got to be some way to do this...